# Fill a fixed array with a sequence of letters

Tags: arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I have 5 a letters sequence, that in loop will need to fill up an array of letters, as shown below. The array I want to fill 
has an allocation of 16 arrays.

How can I get the following result in any language?

```
array =>
    0.["a"],
    1.["b"],
    2.["c"],
    3.["d"],
    4.["e"],
    5.["a"],
    6.["b"],
    7.["c"],
    8.["d"],
    9.["e"],
    10.["a"],
    11.["b"],
    12.["c"],
    13.["d"],
    14.["e"],
    15.["a"]
```

So far I created the array (in Javascript)

```
var ArraySize = 16;

var arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < ArraySize; i++) {
    arr.push(i);
    console.log("arr = " + arr[i] );
}
```

Output:

```
"arr = 0"
"arr = 1"
"arr = 2"
"arr = 3"
"arr = 4"
"arr = 5"
"arr = 6"
"arr = 7"
"arr = 8"
"arr = 9"
"arr = 10"
"arr = 11"
"arr = 12"
"arr = 13"
"arr = 14"
"arr = 15"
```

Comment: In your example, the alphabet has five letters [a,b,c,d,e].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript:

```
var alphabet=['a','b','c','d'];
var arrayLimit =15;
var arr = [];
for (var i=0; i<arrayLimit; i++) 
   arr[i] = alphabet[i%alphabet.length];
```